# Vector Coordinates and linear combination as an arrow will not display on the same plot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, linear-algebra

I am attempting to graph the coordinates of two vectors on a plot (see Part 1 of code snippet) and the linear combination of the two vectors (see Part 2 of code snippet1) on the same plot.  However, in Snippet 1, only the arrow is displaying, though I am not sure why.

In Snippet 2, I was able to get both to print, by reversing the order, but the arrow does not reach the end coordinate w = [2, 1], as expected.  Can anyone advise how I can fix the arrow so it lands on the coordinate (2, 1), (see Plot Image below)?

Snippet 1: Only Arrow displays:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Part 1: Plot points
x = [-2, 2, 2]
y = [-1, -1, 1]

plt.plot(x, y, color='r', linestyle='dashed', linewidth=2, marker='o', markerfacecolor='blue', markeredgecolor='blue')
plt.xlim(-3, 3)
plt.ylim(-2, 2)
y_range = np.arange(-2, 3)
x_range = np.arange(-3, 4)
plt.yticks(y_range)
plt.xticks(x_range)

# Part 2: Plot Vector
v = np.array([-2, -1])
w = np.array([2, 1])

# Creates axes of plot referenced 'ax'
ax = plt.axes()

# Plots red dot at origin (0,0)
ax.plot(*v, 'or')

ax.arrow(*v, *w, color='b', linewidth=2.5, head_width=0.30, head_length=0.35)

# Sets limit for plot for x-axis
plt.xlim(-3, 3)

# Set major ticks for x-axis
major_xticks = np.arange(-3, 4)
ax.set_xticks(major_xticks)

# Sets limit for plot for y-axis
plt.ylim(-2, 2)

# Set major ticks for y-axis
major_yticks = np.arange(-2, 3)
ax.set_yticks(major_yticks)

# Default Grid
plt.grid(visible=True, which='major')

plt.show()
```

Code Snippet 2: Both coordinates and arrow display, however, the head of the arrow does not reach the end coordinate w= [2, 1], as expected:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Part 2: Plot Vector
v = np.array([-2, -1])
w = np.array([2, 1])

# Creates axes of plot referenced 'ax'
ax = plt.axes()

# Plots red dot at origin (0,0)
ax.plot(*v, 'or')

ax.arrow(*v, *w, color='b', linewidth=2.5, head_width=0.30, head_length=0.35)

# Sets limit for plot for x-axis
plt.xlim(-3, 3)

# Set major ticks for x-axis
major_xticks = np.arange(-3, 4)
ax.set_xticks(major_xticks)

# Sets limit for plot for y-axis
plt.ylim(-2, 2)

# Set major ticks for y-axis
major_yticks = np.arange(-2, 3)
ax.set_yticks(major_yticks)

# Part 1: Plot points
x = [-2, 2, 2]
y = [-1, -1, 1]

plt.plot(x, y, color='r', linestyle='dashed', linewidth=2, marker='o', markerfacecolor='blue', markeredgecolor='blue')
plt.xlim(-3, 3)
plt.ylim(-2, 2)
y_range = np.arange(-2, 3)
x_range = np.arange(-3, 4)
plt.yticks(y_range)
plt.xticks(x_range)



# Default Grid
plt.grid(visible=True, which='major')

plt.show()
```

Plot Image:
[image]

Comment: Can you add more explanation on what's going on here? What are the two vectors, `v` and `w`? Where do you do the linear combination of the vectors? If those are the two vectors, wouldn't `v + w = (0, 0)`? I think you have a lot more code here than is necessary and it is distracting from the important details. And I say that because I can't figure out what the important details are.

Comment: According to the [arrow documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.arrow.html) the second two numbers to pass should be the difference between the points rather than the location of the second point.

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing the documentation, I was able to fix with the following code.  Thanks @Ruthc for pointing this out.

```
 ax.arrow(*v, 4, 2, color='b', linewidth=2.5, head_width=0.30, head_length=0.35)
```

Comment: This answer would benefit from more explanation on why this is right and your original code was wrong.